# How to keep buttons from stacking?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my code below, an incredibly early draft, I'm basically trying to get the positioning for a few things. I've got the general flow minus the last two sections but I've hit an issue.

Everything is responsive thanks to bootstrap however when the browser is made small enough the buttons will stack. If you go to 'google.com', rather than stacking the page will just cut off which I think looks better (it will still adapt to the browser window size though).

How can I modify my code to do the same thing or at the very least not look like a jumbled mess when the browser window is small? Also any thoughts on this? I'm not a designer at heart so maybe the page cutting off after a certain point may not be the way to go.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Noted!</title>
</head>
<body>

<section class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row-fluid'>
        <div class='col-md-4'>
            <h1>logo</h1>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-4'>
            <button>login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class='container'>
    <div class='text-center'>
        <h1>motto here</h1>
    </div>
    <div class='row' class='text-center'>
        <div class='col-md-3 col-md-offset-3'>
            <button>facebook button</button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3'>
            <button>twitter button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class='container'>
    <h1>about us and icons</h1>
</section>

<section class='container-fluid'>
    <h1>footer mate</h1>
</section>


</body>

<!-- don't forget to link the angular file -->
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try using `col-xs-*` instead of `col-md-*`? `col-xs-*` will not collapse on the smallest devices.

Comment: this is on my macbook right now, setting it up to be desktop friendly first. isnt md made for computers? that is what is throwing me off as i wasnt expecting this to happen on a chrome browser on a 13 inch macbook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `col-xs-*` classes instead of the `col-md-*` classes if you do not want things to stack on small devices. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options for all the different page sizes and classes to use.

Note that Bootstrap does not care what type of computer you are on for the classes to apply only the screen width. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#width for more information on the width queries bootstrap is doing.

Comment: this is via my macbook chrome browser, that is what concerns me. when this site is more finalized in design ill be adapting it to mobile devices but im wondering why its doing this in a standard computer browser

Comment: `col-md-*` classes will stack at 969px wide so if your screen is less than or equal to that then they will stack.

Comment: Bootstrap only cares about the screen width not what device you are on.

Comment: gotcha, should i just add the xs and everything alongside the md inside the tags then or would that hurt load times in the long run?

Comment: If you want every device to look the same you can just do `col-xs-*` classes. If you want to change the layout for different devices then mix `col-xs-*` with `col-md-*`. There is no performance issue for including both classes.

Comment: I would just replace `col-md` with `col-xs`.

Comment: If this answer fix your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You could set a [min-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) on either a container DIV or on the BODY.

It's not necessarily the "best" option, in that your responsive design isn't adapting to certain screen sizes (meaning you've got a bigger problem), but it's an easy solution until you find a better overall design.

Comment: as of right now this is on my macbook and im trying to get it desktop ready before i dive into mobile adaptability. when i hit smaller screen sizes ill update the md values to xs and etc. but as far as desktop views go is min-width a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

All your button divisions currently are designed keeping in mind the medium screensize. Thus, you will need to add the  along with it.
Remeber xs stands for extra small.

Take a look at the below link:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

This explains the grid system that is made use of by Twitter Bootstrap.